# Inversion in this sentence: "Nothing can/could I do..."

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Is it possible to use an inversion like this:

> *"**Nothing could (can) I do** in that situation."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible and understandable.  However I would only expect to see this form in poetry. It certainly is not used in ordinary conversation.

In everyday modern English we would say:

*There was nothing I could do in that situation.*

---

From the following Google nGram, you can see that "nothing could I" experienced an upsurge in the mid-1800s and its usage *appears* to be increasing now. However I believe the latter is because of the re-publishing of old works in modern editions.

Google nGram: [nothing could I](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing+could+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnothing%20could%20I%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnothing%20could%20I%3B%2Cc0)

Google Books: [Recent publications of older works](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nothing%20could%20i%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1929,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en)